# Hr tag shows nothing after mailing

Tags: html, css, templates

I'm trying to create a newsletter template in order to paint different lines for every product but the HR tag is not working...
I've been trying with divs, table, CSS properties but none of them seems to be a good solution.

It is working in my Chrome but after sending the template to the provider the HR disappears.
Does someone know how to solve it? Why is it?

I've created a table instead of a hr tag, but is not working in Gmail... (working in Outlook, Aol and Yahoo).

```
<table style='border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;'>
        <tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;'>
            <th>&nbsp</th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the presence of `<hr>` tag in your DOM using developer tools, does it exist there in your page or your DOM is not loading that hr tag in first place.

Comment: It is existing. Its just not working when trying to template newsletter to gmail

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. This will work out!

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background:none; border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD; height:1px; width:100%; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `hr` approach works well on Gmail, as well as the latest Outlook also.

```
<hr height="1" style="height:1px; border:0 none; color: #BDBDBD; background-color: #BDBDBD; margin-top:1.5em; margin-bottom:1.5em;">
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Same as before. Doesnt work with Gmail. But thank's anyways